# Recognizing UIBarButtoItems with UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel at runtime?

Tags: ios, ios8, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I would like to check for the presence of a `UIBarButtonItem` that was initialized like this:

```
[UIBarButtonItem initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
                                      target: target 
                                      action: action];
```

How can this be done? It's `title` is apparently `nil` and `UIBarButtonItem` does not expose `systemItem`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just save a reference like

```
UIBarButtonItem *myItem = [UIBarButtonItem initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
                                      target: target 
                                      action: action];
```

Then you can check via `if(myItem != nil) {}`

But I guess I am not understanding your question correctly. Do you want to check whether the button is hidden or not ?

Comment: With a "plain" `UIBarButtonItem` initialized with `initWithTitle:style:target:action:` I would check the title, not introduce another property just for  supporting tests (and next to the existing reference `navigationItem.left/rightBarButtonItem`). My question concerns whether something analogous is possible for "Cancel" buttons as well. Of course, a (duplicated) reference would work as a fallback solution.